# ng-bind-html vs {{interpolation}}

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, angularjs-interpolate

That is my question, what are the pros and cons ?

In my app I am using interpolation but I get errors like this

`{{::sport.name}}` -> `NHL Futures &amp; Props`

and if I use `ng-bind-html`

`ng-bind-html="sport.name"` -> `NHL Futures & Props`

in this case `ng-bind-html` is doing what I want. But, is there something wrong with it ?

Is there one better than the other ?

so tell me, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: ng-bind-html is used to interpret html instead of just displaying the textual content of your variable. {{<b>hi</b>}} will display "<b>hi</b>" but ng-bind-html="<b>hi</b>" will display a bold hi.

Comment: @Okazari why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Okazari hey, but explain a little more, is there something with the performance ? why one is better than the other ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer  `ng-bind-html` sanitize the html using `$sce` while `ng-bind` don't sanitize html..Both are used for different purpose..so we can't compare them on basis of their performance

Comment: @Pureferret wasn't sure it was an answer to the question. Should i ?@NietzscheProgrammer I don't have this knowledge, but in my opinion ng-bind-html should be used only on purpose, when you want some HTML in a variable to be interpreted. In your case this is just a workaround to solve your problem.

Comment: @Okazari I definitely think so. If you wanted to dig into performance, it can be edited in later. But as it stands it sounds pretty complete.

Comment: Look back to the question a few days ago where you found out about `ng-bind-html` and why you started using it in the first place. `text` vs `html`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the main difference between ng-bind and ng-bind-html is the usecase.
ng-bind will just display the text interpretation of your variable but ng-bind-html will interpret the html in your variable.

Let say we have a variable in your scope

```
 $scope.myText = "<b>Hi</b>";
```

ng-bind or {{}} would display

```
 <b>Hi</b>
```

ng-bind-html would display

**Hi**

Another precision is that ng-bind-html can sanitize your html to prevent code injection.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-bind-html` under the covers uses `$element.html` to set the content (after it is either explicitly trusted or sanitized)

`{{ }}` (or the equivalent `ng-bind`) uses `$element.text` (actually `$element[0].textContent`) to set the content.

So, in other words - the first sets the HTML and the second one sets Text content. That is why you are seeing the difference with `&amp;`.

Comment: Another important distinction between `ng-bind` and `{{}}` is that the former allows more control over what your page looks like before Angular loads (if it ever does).